# How to change dynamic css style of button of datalist on DataBinding

Tags: asp.net, datalist

```xml
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand"
    onselectedindexchanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    ondatabinding="DataList1_DataBinding">

    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Hdnqid" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HidnResultStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ResultStatus") %>' />

                <asp:Button ID="Butto" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>'  CommandName="Save&Next"
                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

I want to change color of button accourding to value of table.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using OnDataBound event of the data list. In the event you can get the button as well as your data item properties. Here you can change the properties of the button as below

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = e.Item.FindControl("Butto") as Button;
    HiddenField HidnResultStatus = e.Item.FindControl("HidnResultStatus") as HiddenField;
    string property = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "colorproperty") as string;
    //Here you can change the button color based on the value
    if(HidnResultStatus.Value=="") 
      button.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    if(HidnResultStatus.Value=="1") 
      button.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;

}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Can you debug and check do you get the button, property etc?

Comment: Here is not any error and not working css on datalist button .. protected void DataList1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
            {if(hdn.Value=="")
                {btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;} if(hdn.Value=="1")
                 { btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;}}}

Comment: Did you try the ItemDataBound event as shown above?